# Value is getting changed after assign it to dictionary in Python

Tags: python, string, dictionary

I have created a inputjson variable and then replacing "'" to '\a"' and creating a dictionary and assigning to json key but the output of newjson variable and dictionary key value is different. In dictionary output / is replaced by //. Can anyone help me with the reason behind this issue.

```
inputjson = {"project_path": "Store_Execution_Analytics/DSCI/Tech","project_path_pqm": "Store_Execution_Analytics/DSCI/Tech/","project_path_powerbi": "Store_Execution_Analytics/DSCI/Tech","input_db_name": "rtm_storeexecution_pqm"}
print("The existing json value is: " + str(inputjson))

newjson = str(inputjson).replace(r"'", r'\a"')
print("The new json value is: " + str(newjson))
dict1={}
dict1['json'] = newjson
print(dict1)
```

[image: output]

```
inputjson = {'gen': 'UAT', 'gen2': 'eu', 'json': '{"project_path": "Store_Execution_Analytics/DSCI/Tech","project_path_pqm": "Store_Execution_Analytics/DSCI/Tech/"}'}
```

How can I acheive below output in python?

```
output = {'gen': 'UAT', 'gen2': 'eu', 'json': '{\a"project_path\a": \a"Store_Execution_Analytics/DSCI/Tech\a",\a"project_path_pqm\a": \a"Store_Execution_Analytics/DSCI/Tech/\a"}'}
```

Comment: probably because `newjson` is still a string and `\a` got escaped while printing

Comment: Okay. It will be great if you can help me with solution. My target is to get the dict1['json'] value to be same as new json

Comment: according to your code, you are replacing `'` with `\a"`, so when `inputjson` is converted to string all the double quotes surrounding the keys get converted to single quotes. so the replace methods replaced all the single quotes to `\a"` so technically your dictionary keys does not have an ending or beginning so it cannot be converted back to a dict even by using `ast.literal_eval`.

Comment: this is what happens when you try to convert it back to a dict. `{\a"project_path\a": \a"Store_Execution_Analytics/DSCI/Tech\a", \a"project_path_pqm\a": \a"Store_Execution_Analytics/DSCI/Tech/\a", \a"project_path_power ....                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                ^
SyntaxError: unexpected character after line continuation character
`

Comment: Try `print(dict1['json'])`, and you will see that extra slashes (\\) are not present, I don't know what you are trying to do exactly, but when you replaced characters in `inputjson`, your `dict` became a `str` (`newjson` variable is a string, not dict), so `dict1` has a value of `str` and when you print dictionary it will have different representation compared with printing a string (`print(dict1)` compared to `print(newjson)`).

Comment: @MarkAkritas I have added what I am exactly trying to achieve. I have shared inputjson and output above. Can you please help me

Comment: @Nayanjain I guess you have already achieved your goal, just need some code cleaning..
As was described by others as well, the `print` function represents `dict` and `str` objects differently, so if you print dictionary which has a string inside, and just print that string they'll be represented differently due to their escape characters, but the object itself, the string is the same. I will post an answer with cleaner code.

Answer (score 1):

In python, the `\` character is used to escape characters that otherwise have a special meaning, such as newline `\n`, backslash itself `\\`, or the quote character `\'\"`. See more at https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals.

Now in the first print (i.e. `print("The new json value is: " + str(newjson))`), you pass a string to the `print` function. The `print` function then displays the string in the console with the escaped characters resolved (a newline char will appear as a true line separator instead of the `\n` character, etc.).

In the second print (i.e. `print(dict1)`), the concerned string is a key in the dictionary `dict1`. Printing a dictionary does not resolve escape characters as it prints the [`repr`esentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#repr) of its keys and values. This is why you see the `\\` escaped.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. is it achievable by any other method?I have added input json and output what I am trying to achieve above.

Comment: Frankly I don't understand what you are trying to achieve here. The `output` you want without escaping the special characters is not even a valid json. Try to print the true json value `import json; print(json.dumps(newjson))` to see what it should look like to be valid. That said if you just want that output for any reason, you can do the following: `print("{" + ", ".join(f"{k!r}: '{v}'" for k, v in newjson.items()) + "}")`

Answer (score 0):

This happens because you're putting the string into a dictionary and then printing the entire dictionary. In order for python to represent the dictionary value correctly it has to escape the `\a`'s. You'll see though if you print the value specifically associated with the `json` key in `dict1` it prints as expected.

```
inputjson = {"project_path": "Store_Execution_Analytics/DSCI/Tech","project_path_pqm": "Store_Execution_Analytics/DSCI/Tech/","project_path_powerbi": "Store_Execution_Analytics/DSCI/Tech","input_db_name": "rtm_storeexecution_pqm"}
print("The existing json value is: " + str(inputjson))

newjson = str(inputjson).replace(r"'", r'\a"')
print("The new json value is: " + str(newjson))
dict1={}
dict1['json'] = newjson
print(dict1['json']) // this prints as expected
```

Here's an example of this working. https://www.mycompiler.io/view/GmTFEYm

Answer (score 0):

You need to do the replacement for the `inputjson["json"]`, not for the whole dictionary, if you are interested only in `"json"` field.

```
inputjson = {'gen': 'UAT', 'gen2': 'eu', 'json': '{"project_path": "Store_Execution_Analytics/DSCI/Tech","project_path_pqm": "Store_Execution_Analytics/DSCI/Tech/"}'}

output = inputjson.copy()
output["json"] = output["json"].replace(r'"', r'\a"')

print(output)
print(output['json'])

# Outputs
## {'gen': 'UAT', 'gen2': 'eu', 'json': '{\\a"project_path\\a": \\a"Store_Execution_Analytics/DSCI/Tech\\a",\\a"project_path_pqm\\a": \\a"Store_Execution_Analytics/DSCI/Tech/\\a"}'}
## {\a"project_path\a": \a"Store_Execution_Analytics/DSCI/Tech\a",\a"project_path_pqm\a": \a"Store_Execution_Analytics/DSCI/Tech/\a"}
```

Comment: Still if you see the result of both output and output['json'] there is a difference of \. In output dictionary it is \\a" but in output['json'], it is \a"